# Excel VBA: change table values based on selections in multiselect listbox on userform

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a workbook on which I'm trying to use a userform to control worksheet visibility.

Table (tblDefaultValues) contains data for each worksheet. This table includes columns that contain the default sheet visibility (populates listbox on worksheet open) and the session visibility (current worksheet visibility):

[image: tblDefaultValues]

I am using a multiselect listbox (ListBoxWorksheets) to allow the user to control worksheet visibility. ListBoxWorksheets (with columnwidth property for columns 1 and 4 set to zero to hide these columns) is populated from tblDefaultValues on the Userform_Initialize event like this:

```
    ListBoxWorksheets.ColumnCount = 5
    ListBoxWorksheets.RowSource = "tblDefaultValues"
```

There is a button on ListBoxWorksheets that when clicked I would like to update the value in the SessionVisibility field for the selected rows in tblDefaultValues.

So, for example, to show only those sheets in Category2, the user selects those rows, and clicks a button on the userform. **The goal** is to write "Visible" to the relevant row in the SessionVisibility column of tblDefaultValues.

[image: ListBoxWorksheets_multiselect]

The _Click code for the button I'm using is:

```
Private Sub btnShowOnlySelectedWorksheets_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim i As Long

    'Check if all listbox items are unchecked
    If SelectedRecordCount = 0 Then

        MsgBox "Please make a selection(s) in 'Select Worksheet(s)'!", vbOKOnly, "Not allowed!"
        
        Exit Sub
                      
    End If
  
    'Assign worksheet and table to ws and tbl objects
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetNameLookup")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("tblDefaultValues")

    'loop through listboxWorksheets rows
    For i = 0 To ListBoxWorksheets.ListCount - 1
    
        'if row is selected
        If ListBoxWorksheets.Selected(i) Then
            
            tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "Visible" 'table row = i+1, column is 5
            
            Debug.Print "Selected; row " & i + 1
  
        Else 'row is not selected
                
            tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "Hidden"
         
            Debug.Print "Not selected; row " & i + 1

        End If
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

**What happens** is that only the SessionVisibility value for the first selected sheet is updated in tblDefaultValues but only if the first selected row is also the first row in the listbox (the rest of the selected rows do not seem to be recognized as selected in the listbox and Hidden is transferred into the SessionVisibility column). If only one row in the listbox is selected (and it is not the 1st row), the relevant row in the table is marked as Hidden. If the first selected row in the listbox is not the first row (and multiple rows are selected), everything in tblDefaultValues is marked as Hidden.

If I comment out the `tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value` code lines the Debug.Print writes the expected output, indicating that the selected rows are still recognized as selected in the `For i = 0 To ListBoxWorksheets.ListCount - 1 loop`.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

**One last request**: can someone point me towards a resource for learning how to step through the code in the `For i = 0 To ListBoxWorksheets.ListCount - 1` loop? If I set a break point at the end of the button_Click sub, and step into the code, the listbox opens. But after I select the rows and click button, the code stops at the end of the sub without allowing me to step through it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:

If I put `Debug.Print ListBoxWorksheets.Selected(i) & "; " & i & ";  " & tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value` between both the If...Else and Else...End If lines of the `For i = 0 To ListBoxWorksheets.ListCount - 1` loop here's what happens:

If I comment out **both** `tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "Visible"` **and** `tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "Hidden"` and select multiple rows in the listbox, debug.print gives me the output I expect every time (e.g. "False; 0; unchanged" if the 1st row of the listbox is not selected and "True; 1; unchanged" if the 2nd row is selected...). NB: I set each value in the SessionVisibility column of tblDefaultValues to "unchanged" before running the code.

If I comment out **only** the `tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "Visible"`, debug.print gives me "False; incrementing i ; Hidden" for all of the rows, regardless of selection status.

If I comment out **only** the `tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "Hidden"`, debug.print gives me "False; ***i value for only the 1st selected row*** ; Visible". The remainder of the rows are "False; incrementing i ; unchanged".

What else can I try to work this out? I'm hampered a bit by not knowing how to step through the code without it just running to the break point at the end of the -click procedure after I click the command button.

Happy to upload a sanitized version of the file if anyone thinks it would be helpful and are willing to take a look.

Thanks again!

Comment: Try to insert the sheet name before the ListBoxWorksheets sg. like this `Worksheets("XXXXXXX").ListBoxWorksheets......`

Comment: Thanks for responding... I don't really understand your suggestion as ListBoxWorksheets is on a UserForm... but, I tried this: `For i = 0 To Worksheets("Sheet1").ListBoxWorksheets.ListCount - 1`  and got an "Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)"

Comment: btw. SelectedRecordCount where is defined?

Comment: I checked listbox selection, and it works in my test with the third row selected want to set  the value to "Visible". Obviously i didn't make a pivottable, but according this there is the problem.  Insert this line after `If ListBoxWorksheets.Selected(i) Then`  : `Debug.Print tbl.DataBodyRange.Address` and check the result in the immediate window.

Comment: `Debug.Print tbl.DataBodyRange.Address` returns $M$4:$Q$36... this corresponds to the cell range of tblDefaultValues.

Comment: `SelectedRecordCount` is a function in the same module that counts the number of rows selected and returns a value based on 0, 1 or multiple rows selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason: When you overwrite a cell of the ListObject all selections are deleted in the ListBox.

The solution:

Replace

```
  ListBoxWorksheets.RowSource = "tblDefaultValues"
```

with

```
  ListBoxWorksheets.List = tblDefaultValues.DataBodyRange.value
```

Answer (score 0):

As Black cat suggested, using `ListBoxWorksheets.List = tblDefaultValues.DataBodyRange.value` to populate the listbox instead of `ListBoxWorksheets.RowSource = "tblDefaultValues"` solved the problem.
Adding for beginners/tinkerers like me, that I also had to set tblDefaultValues as follows for this to work:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblDefaultValues")
ListBoxWorksheets.List = tbl.DataBodyRange.value
```